# WSCInstallProviderAndChains failed

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, winsock2

I am trying to install lsp dll on windows 7, when i install it the function `InstallProviderVista` gives me this error `InstallProviderVista: WSCInstallProviderAndChains failed: 10104`

Answer (score 0):

solved by exporting the WSPStartup function in the DLL